# Loading a shape using drawable on Android

Tags: java, android, xml, background, drawable

I am trying to load a shape using drawable programmatically so as to make the background color more stylish.

Basically, loading a shape using XML file is simple:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle" >
<gradient
    android:startColor="#ffffff"
    android:centerColor="#00ffff"
    android:endColor="#000000"
    android:type="linear"
    android:angle="90"/>
```

However, I am trying to download this **XML file from the server** since it has to be changed seasonally. (For example, spring is to pink, summer is to blue, and autumn is to orange)

After downloading the XML file, which is located in /data/data/package/resources/shape.xml, I tried to load this background colorset using GradientDrawable since it is all about the gradient.

There are lots of how-to guides about creating a new gradient, but there aren't about applying a pre-loaded gradient.

I tried this:

```
 view.setBackground(GradientDrawable.createFromPath("/data/data/package/resources/shape.xml"));
```

*Here, the view is the activity file, like RelativeLayout or anything else*

However, the result is the default background color, which is blue.

Now I changed the drawable to:

```
view.setBackground(ShapeDrawable.createFromPath("/data/data/package/resources/shape.xml"));
```

*I changed the drawable option to ShapeDrawable since the XML contains Shape*

The result is same, nothing has changed. Changing to the normal drawable doesn't help solve the problem.

Is there another way to apply the **XML file from external storage** to the drawable? Otherwise, what I wrote is the method to apply but there are some mistakes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply get a view to your layout using findViewById and set its background.
Make sure you store your xml in the drawable folder.

For a constraintLayout

```
ConstraintLayout constraintLayout=findViewById(R.id.clay);
constraintLayout.setBackground(getDrawable(R.drawable.prac_shape));
```

`prac_shape` is the id of the shape element.

EDIT: to build a gradient dynamically via java:

```
GradientDrawable gradient = new GradientDrawable(GradientDrawable.Orientation.TOP_BOTTOM, new int[]  {getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent),getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark)});
gradient.setShape(GradientDrawable.RECTANGLE);
constraintLayout.setBackground(gradient);
```

You can play around witht this to set it as you like. You just need to parse your request and pass the appropriate params to the constructor and the methods.

Comment: The XML file can be changed and downloaded from the server, so I want to load the file from external storage.

Comment: I've update the answer to include dynamic drawable creation.

Comment: It is really weird so I uploaded another question

Comment: does this not work? I am sure it does as I tested it on my phone :p

Comment: it just doesn't work and shows me white screen (the default background)

Comment: Did you follow the above code? You need to get a reference to the parent layout and then set the gradient. Some java snippet code of your attempt will be useful.

Comment: I followed, but I wasn't able to load the xml files from stroage

Comment: That is beyond the scope of this question. If you are planning on loading an xml file from storage, id suggest using an XML parser to parse it and put values in a map and then access it from there to set the values of the gradient. If you are not able to load the file at all that merits a completely different question for which more info would be required on the errors being presented.